# Meaning of $\searrow$ notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I was reading a paper which contained the phrase "... for any sequence $c_n \searrow c$ there exists $n_0$ such that ..." I am not familiar with this notation, does $\searrow$ have some common mathematical meaning? elsewhere in the paper, the notation $\nearrow$ is also used in similar context. I tried a google search, but I was unsure which search terms to include in order to find information.

Comment: It means that 1) $\{c_n\}$ converges to $c$, and 2) $\{c_n\}$ is nonincreasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that $c_n$ converges to $c$ from above.

Answer (score 3):

As an example $$c_n:=c+\frac1n \searrow c \qquad \text{as}\;\;n \to +\infty$$ while $$c_n:=c-\frac1n \nearrow c \qquad \text{as}\;\;n \to +\infty$$